# Concatenate quotes around a list in Python

Tags: python

I have the following list that needs to be saved as a variable with quotes around it. I tried adding singles quotes before and after but not having much luck.

```
myvar = "'''" + mylist + "'''"
```

mylist:

```
[{'svn_tag': '20150624r1_6.36_gameofthrones', 'module': 'ariaapi'}, {'svn_tag': '20150620r1_6.36_gameofthrones', 'module': 'api'}]
```

The required output is:

```
myvar = '''[{'svn_tag': '20150624r1_6.36_gameofthrones', 'module': 'ariaapi'}, {'svn_tag': '20150620r1_6.36_gameofthrones', 'module': 'api'}]'''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use string formatting.

```
myvar = "'''{}'''".format(mylist)
```

Comment: However `format` will convert `mylist` to a string, so there's no need to call `str()`.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm more used to assembling strings with `+` and `join()`.

Comment: Note that this will _not_ work properly if a triple single quote appears anywhere in your list.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin - It'll work, it just may not have the exact quote representation of the original (if that representation in the new format is literally impossible). Worst case, it'll use backslash escapes where necessary.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - I should have been more specific.  It depends on what he's _doing_ with the variable.  For example, `mylist = ['hi there', 'foo bar', "'''"]; print("'''{}'''".format(mylist))` will quite happily render `'''['hi there', 'foo bar', "'''"]'''`.  If the goal is to print out something that can be exec'ed later, this will not be happy.

Comment: `print()` prints the object's `__str__` representation, not its `__repr__` representation. I think the chances of having a `list` with triple quotes, adding triple quotes around the `__str__` of the `list`, printing the whole string to some output (console/file/etc.), and then using `exec()` on that are, on the whole, slim to `None`. As an aside, if all that was really wanted was a string representation of the original `list`, then `str(mylist)` would suffice - but that wasn't the question, and I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

`"'''" + str(myList)  + "'''"` should work. You just need to call `str()` on your list, currently you are concatenating a string and a list which throws an error.

Comment: You don't have to escape quotes if they're of a different type than the ones that enclose the string (or if it's a triple-quoted string containing no more than three quotes in a row).

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to have a perfectly general facility to print out (or write out to a file) strings that can later be re-parsed by Python, then you should be careful not to use the answer provided by @TigerhawkT3 if there is any chance that the data you are writing out also includes strings with embedded triple-quotes.  A variation on that answer may be used to insure that any embedded strings with triple single quotes are properly escaped:

```
>>> mylist = ['hi there', 'foo bar', '"""', "'''", '"', "''"]

>>> print("'''{}'''".format(mylist))
'''['hi there', 'foo bar', '"""', "'''", '"', "''"]'''

>>> print("'''{}'''".format('{}'.format(mylist).replace("'''", r"\'\'\'")))
'''['hi there', 'foo bar', '"""', "\'\'\'", '"', "''"]'''
```